# Android Webview/textview combination XML example

Tags: android, webview, textview

Does someone have an example of a split screen xml layout, where the top half of the screen is a webview and the bottom half is a textview/listview or imageview….?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's pretty trivial, just like any other view.

```
<LinearLayout orientation="vertical" ...>
    <WebView layout_height="0dp" layout_weight="1" ... />
    <TextView layout_height="0dp" layout_weight="1" ... />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Ahh man! I tried that, I must have set something else up wrong, one kept overriding the other. Now I know it can be done and just like I was trying to I can continue. So not trivial to newbies. Thanks Mike!